# json - как понять, когда документ загрузился?

Tags: jquery, json, javascript

json - как понять, когда документ загрузился?
к примеру есть такой код

```
$.getJSON('/index2.php', {n: nub}, function(obj){
$('#content').html(obj.content);
var date=obj.date;
$('#content').slideDown("slow")
});
```

Блок разворачивается раньше и поэтому появление получается резким, как сделать, чтобы оно было плавным?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Как вариант, к #content поставить display: none.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Выполнение callback-функции - это и есть факт того, что json загрузился.

Answer (score 2):

По Вашему примеру:

```
$.getJSON('/index2.php', {n: nub}, function(obj){
$('#content').html(obj.content);
var date=obj.date;
$('#content').slideDown("slow")
})
.success( function() { alert('success');} )
.error(function() { alert("error"); })
.complete(function() { alert("complete"); });
```

почитайте гдето в середине страницы [getJSON описание jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)